# StringBuilder .ToString() throws OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

`list` is a string builder that includes a csv that I'm requesting from a website, `toString()` is crashing.

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

It's worth mentioning that my `Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64` is using 5GB of memory, which wasn't the case before.

I tried the following:

- Check if I have WebCompanion to uninstall [I didn't]
- Tried to turn off BrowserLink in VS
- Restarted my machine

I have 3GB of free memory which should be enough to convert a 100MB string.

[image]

Comment: [“Out Of Memory” Does Not Refer to Physical Memory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/)

Comment: Is it 32 bit or 64 bit process? I see Length property = 325M which is equal to 650MB of memory.

Comment: my debugging options are any, but it's running 32-bit

Comment: As You can see from output, there is maximal value which is equals to size of Int32 -> 2147483647. Seems not be the case for "maximal memory usage". Are You sure that this running out of memory is linked to this conversion & "ToString()" calling?

Comment: @Tatranskymedved yes, that's the line asp.net crashes on

Comment: How often do You call the method in a row? It might be an issue if You call this method 2.. 3... 50 times in a row without GC clearing the memory. E.g. during work with files (IO stream) etc. I think we should look on this from bigger perspective -> we need the info around.

Comment: If you are downloading hundreds of MB using a `StringBuilder`, you are not doing it right. Please consider some kind of `Stream` instead.

Comment: At least try to set initial `Capacity` to 350000000 and then look what will happen. Also can you just see in debugger what is going on with memory usage and garbage collector?

Comment: You are trying to allocate memory that is over 650MB in size. Objects this large can't be optimized by the CLR for efficiency, and as such can easily cause fragmentation to occur in working memory, which in turn can cause an `OutOfMemoryException` to be thrown even if the available memory isn't entirely exhausted.

Comment: Furthermore, I have to second what Anders has said - if your program is dealing with strings this large, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Abion47 the string is a csv file with few hundred thousands of lines, even if I write to the response directly it still causes this exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the virtual limit on StringBuilder. if you're not using stream, then do a partial read, read strings up to a certain size, then write them into your text, then empty the builder and repeat.